# How to get the identity page URL from the controller?

Tags: c#, url, .net-core, identity

I need to use 'forgot password' functionality in my MVC controller. With .NET Core 2.1 the identity part is separated in `Area/Identity/Account`.

I need to use this part which generates URL for password reset.

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ResetPassword",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { code },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

But I am not able to generate the URL the same way in my custom controller.

Any ideas how to generate URL for Page in action of common controller?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the above problem? I'm currently in a similar situation.

Comment: Yes I did. Now you can see the answer bellow this post.

Comment: Cheers for updating! Meanwhile I found the answer you where looking for with using Url.Page I've updated this below as a potential answer as well

Answer (score 3):

```
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(applicationUser);
var callbackUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/Identity/Account/ResetPassword?code={code}";
```

Comment: If this was your solution, please check the checkmark next to the answer score so future readers know it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            "/Account/ResetPassword",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { area = "Identity", code },
            protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

You will need to specify area as a value in using Url.Page to generate a correct link from with a mvc Controller. That will do the trick.